# Tree (graph theory)

Tags: combinatorics

In how many trees with $ n $ vertices the number of leaves is exactly:a.$2$ b.$n-1$
Why in $b$ Inclusion–exclusion principle need to be used while in $a$ Factorial? answer for a is: $(nC2)*(n-2)!$ answer for b: $(nC3)*(3^{n-2}-3*2^{n-2}+3)$

Comment: Your answer to b when $n=4$ is ${4\choose3}(3^2-3\cdot2^2+3)=4(9-12+3)=0$.  Something is wrong here!

Answer (score 0):

A [tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28graph_theory%29) on $n$ vertices has $n-1$ edges.  Hence the sum of the degrees of the vertices is $2n-2$, by the [Handshaking Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma).

Hints:

1. If there are two vertices of degree $1$ (i.e., two leaves), then the $n-2$ other vertices have degree $\geq 2$, ... (Here $n \leq 1$ needs to be treated separately.)
2. If there are $n-1$ vertices of degree $1$, then the remaining vertex has degree ...  (Here $n \leq 2$ needs to be treated separately.)

Answer (score 0):

a. There is only one tree $P_n$ (a path on $n$ vertices) with n vertices in which the number of leaves is exactly 2.

b. There is only one tree star (in which a single vertex is adjacent to $n-1$ pendant vertices) with n vertices in which the number of leaves is exactly $n-1$.